# Splitting Values Between 2 Employees Possible Group By

Tags: t-sql

We an incentive scheme that scored to staff via 'Points'. I have written an SP so that we can dynamically change these values day to day however I am struggling in my own head to figure the best way to split the values between two different agents.

**The Setup**

The source table simply looks like below:

```
Department  |   Policy      |Opening Advisor    |   Closing Advisor     |   Agg Pts     |   Aff Pts     |   Rnl Pts |
Sales A     |   LYJX01PC01  |       Sally       |       Sally           |       0       |       3       |      0    |
Sales A     |   MUMP01TW01  |       Sally       |       John            |       0       |       0       |      3    |
```

This table is two separate tables, the first being the Opening Table and then the second being the Closing Table. These are joined by using the 'Branch' which is a column I've not put on here and then 'Policy' to keep it simple, Policy is what joins these 2 tables.

**The Idea**

The idea here is that the Points Per Policy are split 50/50 if the Opening Advisor and the Closing Advisor are different.

Line 1 the Opening and Closing Advisor is Sally, so for that policy she would receive all the points, however on Line 2 she opened the Policy however John closed it.

This would split the points out between them both i.e. 3/2 = 1.5. The output would then be similar to below:

**The Output**

```
Department  |   Policy      |   Advisor     |   Agg Pts |   Aff Pts |   Rnl Pts |
Sales A     |   LYJX01PC01  |   Sally       |       0   |       1.5 |   0       |
Sales A     |   LYJX01PC01  |   John        |       0   |       1.5 |   0       |
Sales A     |   MUMP01TW01  |   Sally       |       0   |       0   |   3       |
```

In my mind all I'm doing is GROUPING by Policy and Advisor and then splitting the points IF Opening / Closing Advisor differ, however putting that down in SQL I'm just turning circle and its one of those moments I need some exterior advice.

Comment: Which column connects an opening/closing event?  Surely not `Policy` since this is different for each of the two rows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess the bit I have missed in all fairness is the closing Advisor comes from a separate table I join the table on an integer value called Branch and the Policy.